# How can I display count of duplicates in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

Consider below arraylist that consists of duplicates. How would I filtering out  integer 89 that occurred 4 times e.g 89:4 .  Expecting output 89 : 4

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61, 98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 89, 89, 89, 89 );         
Map<Integer ,Long > map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c ->c , Collectors.counting())) ;
map.forEach(   (k , v ) -> System.out.println( k + " : "+ v ));
```

//I am  Expecting  output below 
**89 : 4**

// Actual output (key, Values)pairs of above code snippet like below 
1 : 2
98 : 1
2 : 1
67 : 1
3 : 1
5 : 1
8 : 1
41 : 1
13 : 1
15 : 1
21 : 2
55 : 1
89 : 4
25 : 1
61 : 1

Comment: What is so special about `89` or `4` here? Are you trying to find the most frequent item in your List?

Comment: I got Answer           List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61, 98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 89, 89, 89, 89 );

     
        final Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> max = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(
                        Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(max.get());

Comment: you can keep any Integer I am not specific about 89 , replace 89 with some random Integer It is fine with me @KorayTugay

Comment: @sekhar Your question title differs from your expectation a lot. Did you mean to say to find the max occurring integer and its count?

Comment: yes, to finding the max occurrences of duplicate integers and its count in arraylist @nullpointer

Answer (score 2):

You may do it like so,

```
Entry<Integer, Long> maxOccurence = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

Comment: This only prints 89.

Comment: I need to print 89 : 4 , meaning 89 occurrence is 4 times , Shown you like 89:4 , but is printing 89?

Comment: @sekhar this prints `89=4`

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), you can use `topOccurrences`.

```
List<Integer> list = 
    Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61, 98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 89, 89, 89, 89 );
MutableList<ObjectIntPair<Integer>> top = Lists.adapt(list).toBag().topOccurrences(1);
System.out.println(top.makeString());
```

If you want all duplicates, you can use `selectDuplicates`. This filters out 1, 21 and 89.

```
MutableBag<Integer> dupes = Lists.adapt(list).toBag().selectDuplicates();
System.out.println(dupes.toStringOfItemToCount());
```

You can also do this without boxing the primitives.

```
IntList list =
    IntLists.mutable.with(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61, 98, 15, 25, 41, 67, 55, 89, 89, 89, 89);

MutableList<IntIntPair> top = list.toBag().topOccurrences(1);
System.out.println(top.makeString());

IntBag dupes = list.toBag().selectDuplicates();
System.out.println(dupes.toStringOfItemToCount());
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

The other way would be like this

```
Map<Integer, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
int maxCount = 0;
  for (Integer i : list) {
   maxCount = Integer.max(maxCount , temp.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum));
  }
int finalMax = maxCount;
temp.values().removeIf(v->v!= finalMax);
```

or

---

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
    int maxCount = 0;
    int maxKey = 0;
    for (Integer i : list) {
        int count = temp.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);
        if (maxCount < count)
            maxKey = i;
        maxCount = Integer.max(maxCount , count);
    }
    System.out.println(maxKey + " :" + maxCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and memory friendly version. It does have a bad big-O at O(n^2), but for small lists provides best performance in highly concurrent environments with GC pressure, because HashMaps and Map.Entry objects take space and make bad use of CPU caching:

```
import static java.util.Collections.frequency;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
...
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 
        61, 98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 89, 89, 89, 89 );

list.stream()
  .max(comparingInt(x -> frequency(list, x)))
  .map(x -> x + " : " + frequency(list,x))
  .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Prints `89 : 4` i.e. `<most frequent int> : <num occurences>`

Comment: It is hard coded , I mean 4 occurrences were hard coded

Comment: Yes, now I finally understand the question, after reading the discussions. You should have said "max occurences" in your question. Will either contribute a better / alternative answer or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache [Bag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html)

> Defines a collection that counts the number of times an object appears in the collection.
>   Suppose you have a Bag that contains {a, a, b, c}. Calling getCount(Object) on a would return 2, while calling uniqueSet() would return {a, b, c}.

[Example](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-bag)

> ```
>  Bag<Integer> bag = new HashBag<>(
>  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4));         
>  assertThat(2, equalTo(bag.getCount(1)));
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Hope, it will help...

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61,
            98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 89, 89, 89, 89 );
Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> max = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));

if(max.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(max.get());
}
```

Comment: why do you want 89? as 89 is the max? or count of 89 is the max?

Comment: List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61, 98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 89, 89, 89, 89 );
      

        final Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> max = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(
                        Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(max.get());

Comment: Consider some other number(replace with some random Integers instead of 89)  , I am not specific about 89,Like this List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 61,
            98, 15, 25, 41, 67,55, 99, 99, 99, 99 );

Comment: So in this case 99:4 will be output as max number of occurrence is 4. right?